# How retrieve to all rows properly in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Coming to a problem where I am trying to retrieve my data from my database and the only data I get is the one object that is my first row. I want to get all my 3 rows shown as a list and not get just one row. is there a work around with my code below? Thank you for your help.

This is what I did:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "jobs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> getSalary(@RequestParam(value = "autocomplete") String autocompleteValue) {

    List<AutoComplete> list = autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue);
    return Arrays.asList(merge(list));

}


ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> merge(List<AutoComplete> list){

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String> > finalList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(3);
    ArrayList<String> annual = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> biweekly = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> hourly = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        AutoComplete autoComplete = list.get(i);
        if (autoComplete.getAnnual() != null) {
            annual.add(autoComplete.getAnnual());
        }
        if (autoComplete.getBiweekly() != null) {
            biweekly.add(autoComplete.getBiweekly());
        }
        if (autoComplete.getHourly() != null) {
            hourly.add(autoComplete.getHourly());
        }
    }
    finalList.add(annual);
    finalList.add(biweekly);
    finalList.add(hourly);
    return finalList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that criteria `findAllByJobClassCdIsContaining(jobClassCd)` return all 3 entries ? Some where i feel that this is your custom method, not the original provided by JPA Repository.
Try using `findAllByJobClassCdContaining(jobClassCd)` or simply `findAll()` to see if it return more than 1 entry.

**UPDATE** - i supposed that it is database that is not returning correct value, but after your comment i got that where exactly the problem is. Please try modifying your code as below. For this you may need to define 3 new arraylist and a parent list. Then iterate you list retrieved from database to form the final list.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String> > finalList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(3); 
ArrayList<String> annual = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> biweekly = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> hourly = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
AutoComplete autoComplete = list.get(i);
if (autoComplete.getAnnual() != null) {
      annual.add(autoComplete.getAnnual());
}
if (autoComplete.getBiweekly() != null) {
     biweekly.add(autoComplete.getBiweekly());
}
if (autoComplete.getHourly() != null) {
    hourly.add(autoComplete.getHourly());
}
}
finalList.add(annual);
finalList.add(biweekly);
finalList.add(hourly);
return finalList;
```

Comment: just getting one object. because in my controller I have `AutoComplete acc = list.get(0);` ... All I need to do is get my three rows as shown "Something like this that I want to return:" in my question above.

Comment: I just updated my answer, please try the given solution and let me know the results

Answer (score 0):

```
Modifiy your model class like below

public class AutoComplete {

ArrayList<String> Annual ;
ArrayList<String> Biweekly ;
ArrayList<String> Hourly;

 public ArrayList<String>getHourly() {
        return Hourly;
    }

    public void setHourly(ArrayList<String> hourly) {
        Hourly = hourly;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getBiweekly() {
        return Biweekly;
    }

    public void setBiweekly(ArrayList<String> biweekly) {
        Biweekly = biweekly;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAnnual() {
        return Annual;
    }

    public void setAnnual(ArrayList<String> annual) {
        Annual = annual;
    }

}

Now in your autocompleteRepository.findAllByJobClassCdIsContaining(String jobClassCd) Method Store all the rows in arrays and then set array in to model class return on single model object called AutoComplete .

public AutoComplete  findAllByJobClassCdIsContaining(String jobClassCd){

/// Declare arrays
ArrayList<String> Annual = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Biweekly = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Hourly= new ArrayList<>();

//Retrieve from DB and set into 3 arrays 

   // code 
     While(row.next()){ 
  ///  get from db and set to arrays.
     }


// set arrays to object
AutoComplete  acc=new AutoComplete  ();
acc.setHourly(Hourly);
acc.setsetBiweekly(Biweekly );
acc.setAnnual(Annual);

}

All other method in service and domain layer will be modified accordingly.
```

Comment: Do I need to modify in repository or in controllers? Because, I believe the changes will be in controllers?

Comment: can you just do in my controller with my code above?

Comment: @Sbaldwin you to make changes in all controllers,model and repository.  in repository when you are retrieving your value  you have to store in values in array using while loop and wherever you are calling those methods return type will be changed.(controller also)  now you will be return single object (AutoComplete ) which has array of values.

Comment: can you please show me a working example in order to see how these all works out? here is my full source code: https://github.com/va-developer/AutoCompleteAPI/

Comment: Please try by your self and let me know if you face any issue. or if you are have some concern in understanding of solution provided by . let me know i would be happy to help you. :)

Comment: can I do in my controller class or should I create a new POJO class?